# Require a file to be called from the command line

Tags: ruby, command-line, optparse

So I know how to use optparser to use the command line to call a specific method in my program. But, is there a way to use optparse where the user is required to specify a file in order to have the command work? Like for example when using this code:

```
test.rb    
#!/usr/bin/ruby
read = File.readlines(file)
puts read
```

The user would be required to specify a specific file the program needs to read.

```
test.rb -b test.txt
```

Is there a way to do this or am I still too new to ruby to fully understand how it works?

Comment: `ARGV` may be your friend.

Comment: ARGV? I've come across that a couple times but I still have yet to understand how that work. Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about `optparse`, but you can do something like this perhaps:

```
#test.rb    
#!/usr/bin/ruby
file = ARGV[0]
read = File.readlines(file)
puts read
```

then run the file in command line, passing the file name as an argument. Where ARGV[0] corresponds with the first argument passed:

```
$ ruby test2.rb test2.rb
##test.rb    
##!/usr/bin/ruby
#file = ARGV[0]
#read = File.readlines(file)
#puts read
```

Comment: And that will work with any kind of file, right? I'm sorry if I'm coming of as being slow but like i mentioned before I don't have a good grasp of how ARGV works.

Comment: Yes it will work for any file. In the answer above I just chose the script file itself. Try it with another file and see, if following the example above just make sure the file being read is in the same directory as the script.